# Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure- Jenkins iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, jenkins, xcode10

Whenever I am trying to build my project using Jenkins, I am getting the following error:

I have tried the following things already:

1. pod install/update
2. scheme name "shared" checkbox selected in "manage schemes"
3. specifying shell command " install"

Nothing worked, apart from above if anyone has a solution for my issue will really appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Below is my error log getting from Jenkins while building project:

```
/Users/<User>/.jenkins/workspace/<Project-parent-folder>/<Project>/build/<Project>.build/Release-iphoneos/<Project>.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MyCell.o -embed-bitcode-marker
/Users/<User>/.jenkins/workspace/<Project-parent-folder>/<Project>/<Project>/MVC/Controller/DetailVC.swift:10:8: error: no such module 'SwiftyJSON'
import SwiftyJSON
       ^

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    CompileSwift normal arm64
(2 failures)
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please help.

Comment: can you add your pod file also

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the **Pods folder** and **Podfile.lock** file from the project.

Also, remove derived data from your project and from Jenkins (/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData)

Now again install the Pods.